# TVOS Focus between collectionview cell to another

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I have a nested Collectionview which like the image below. I am wonder if I can change focus just like the image below?
Thanks before hand

current behavior
[image]

Expected behavior
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try override `preferred focus`
i.e.

```
override var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    return collectionView.visibleCells.first
}
```